# Creating custom property in Qt with c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and trying to create a custom property in Qt.
For keeping it short i have merged the .h and .cpp file here but they are different in my main project.
My main.cpp is

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "message.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Message msg;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("msg", &msg);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    qRegisterMetaType<MessageBody*>("MessageBody*");
    return app.exec();
}
```

My message.h is

```
#include<messageBody.h>
class Message : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MessageBody* body READ body WRITE setBody NOTIFY bodyChanged)
    MessageBody ob;
public:
    MessageBody* body()
    {
        return &ob;
    }
    void setBody(MessageBody* body)
    {
         ob.textUpdate(body->text());
         emit bodyChanged();
    }

signals:
    void bodyChanged();
};
```

My messageBody.h is

```
class MessageBody : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE textUpdate NOTIFY textChanged)
    QString ori_text;
public:
    void textUpdate(const QString& new_txt)
    {
        if(new_txt != ori_text)
        {
            ori_text=new_txt;
            emit textChanged();
        }
    }
    QString text()
    {
        return ori_text;
    }

    signals:
        void textChanged();
};
```

My main.qml is

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Text{
        msg.body: "Hello, world!" //"Error here."
                             //I am expecting MessageBody::textUpdate()
                             //to get called i.e write method of Property
    }
}
```

While executing, I am getting an error

```
 qrc:/main.qml:18 Cannot assign to non-existent property "msg"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get 100% what you're tring to achieve, but maybe something like this:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Text{
        text: msg.body.text
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        msg.body.text = "Hello, world!"
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "message.h"
#include "MessageBody.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qRegisterMetaType<MessageBody*>("MessageBody");
    qRegisterMetaType<Message *>("Message");

    Message msg;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("msg", &msg);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this initially also but i am getting error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined" for line text: msg.body.text and "TypeError: Type error" for line msg.body.text = "Hello World"

Comment: I've edit my post. Could you add the ```qRegisterMetaType<Message *>("Message *");```and see if this helps?

Comment: I did as u said, still not working. Same error again.

Comment: Updated  again :) Please note that I also update main.qml! ```Component.onCompleted``` was in the wrong place in my initial post...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using your `msg` object as if it was an existing property of the QML `Text Element` and it is not that's why Qt give you this error.

I am not a QML pro developer but as I know you could or call your `msg.body` with an existing signal of the Text Object such as `onTextChange` o `Component.onCompleted` or try to create a `custom QML object` inheriting from `Text` and that has a custom property `msg.body` which make a link with your `msg.body` of your c++ object.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with creating a Custom QML Object.